# Display HTML page with external JavaScript via Android assets

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

So I have been looking everywhere and doesn't seems to find working answer for this. I have dynamic html page create using iMapBuilder and it has 3 external js files. Before I have added dynamic contents html was working just fine being under assets directory with following command:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ground_floor);
        WebView wv;
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imap5custom.html");
    }
}
```

After adding dynamic content with 3 Java Script external files which are also under root assets folder, html doesn't work any more. I have tried:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL
```

but still didn't work for me.

Comment: How does the HTML file reference the scripts?

Comment: What's the exact problem you're seeing? 'doesn't work' is pretty vague. If you're running KitKat - have you tried connecting to the WebView using devtools?